# Retrieve array of core data element

Tags: arrays, core-data, nsfetchrequest, swift5

I want retrieve core data and print the entire array in the log file. Right now my function converts a array to a double and then finds the average of all the numbers All I want to do is print the array of all the elements of the string "ee" in the log file

```
    func performAction() {
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            var retrievedData = [Double]()
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let value = data.value(forKey: "ee") as? String {
                    retrievedData.append(Double(value) ?? 0)
                }
            }

            let arraySum = retrievedData.reduce(0, +)
            print(arraySum/Double(retrievedData.count))
            let venus = (arraySum/Double(retrievedData.count))
            average.text = String("\(venus)")

        } catch {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what do you actually get in this situation? What is the error / weird looking behaviour?

Comment: The error is I don’t know how to print all the elements of the array in the log file so in array Ee the user can have [ben,Sam,ian]. I want to know how to print that in log file

Comment: Not too familiar with Swift log files, but are you speeking of this https://github.com/apple/swift-log? The one you call like this `logger.info("Hello World!")` ?

Comment: I messed up I mean the debug area not the log area.

Comment: like `print(value)` in the `for data in result { }` for instance? Not sure I get you to be honest

Comment: That Works. Thanks it.